# How to check if a string is a sub-sequence of another in scheme

Tags: recursion, substring, scheme, racket

I'm trying to make a recursive function which take in a string, string-1 and checks if another string, string-2, is a sub-sequence. I got a few base cases working but cannot get the whole program to work.

What I tried doing is implementing the "member?" function. What I wanted it to do is to check if each element in string 2 is a part of string 1 but also, check if they characters are in order.

For example, given the the string: hello, the function will produce true if the other string is: hel, ell, ello, hello or hlo. The function will produce false if the other string is: ehl, oll or helllo.

```
(define (possible-subset? word subset-word)
  (cond [(> (length (string->list subset-word)) (length (string->list word)) ) false]
        [(equal? (string->list word) (string->list subset-word)) true]))
```

The code presented above takes care of the clear giveaways that will tell you if the word is a subset.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Related: [_How to compute the number of times pattern in one list appears in other list in Scheme?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54758619/633183)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take hello and hlo as the example.

1. Do both strings start with the same character, if they do remove it from both.

With that hello and hlo reduces to ello and lo

2. if the string does not start with same character as the query string, skip forward in the string until the first character of the string is the same as the first character of the query

With that ello and lo reduces to llo and lo then rule 1 applies again resulting in lo and o where rule 2 reduces that to o and o which rule 1 reduces to two empty strings

3. If the query is empty, the result is a match. If the string is empty but the query is not, the result is not a match.

With that by rule 3 the result is a match.